# How to screenshot an area on screen as soon as it changes?

Tags: screenshot

Is it possible to select an area on screen (windows in virtualbox, fwiw), then have software watch that area and repeatedly screenshot it as soon as it changes? Effectively making a frame-by-frame movie (with pics in different files) without repeating frames.